# Adding an attribute to html <video> tag using Javascript or Jquery. - WordPress Case

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I have a WordPress installation and I share some links like the following to students watching courses - presentations online.

https://emgncv.net/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/108_I_Interpretation_Case_Study.mp4

The big issue that I am facing here is that I want to find a piece of code (probably Javascript or Jquery) to add "**On document ready**" so when students load the presentations on their browsers not being able to download the video from the 3-dots menu on the right bottom corner of the media player. Please, view the screenshot attached.

[image]

For the records, I have noticed this only on Google Chrome and Microsoft Edge. Mozilla does not offer such a download option.

What I have already tried is the following:

`$('video').attr('controlsList', 'nodownload');`

FYI, I have placed this code in a section where my WordPress theme provider lets me add some custom JS code. The section works pretty fine. I have already implemented others functions and everything works properly.

Do you have any ideas on what I will need to look at to achieve the following by default when my students load their courses on browsers?

[image]

Thank you so much in advance,

George.

Comment: The no download should work, can’t you add it directly on the html video element itself? No real need for JavaScript. Plus it’s rendered in the DOM if you ad no download to controlList

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot add it directly to the HTML video element itself, and that is why I am searching for a solution. All these video files are simply uploaded to my server via FTP and then I share with students the links to the directory paths created. That is why I thought that a Javascript code "On Document ready" could solve my hands.